# Consuming web service and transferring data to database using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, xml, web-services, ssis

I have consumed simple web service to add numbers via SSIS and now I have saved the output into xml file which I have stored on my local drive, now I have to access that added result from xml file through **XML DATA FROM VARIABLE** access mode and store that result in sql database via SSIS,

When I am trying to do this ,XML source is unable to take the inputs and connect to OLEDB destination, actually I have also created user defined variable but don't know how to use that variable since that variable does not appear in the dropdown option of XML location of XML editor.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, since I am newbie to SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the connection string property (or most any property) for your datasource DYNAMICALLY through the use of ***Expressions*** in SSIS.  In your case you can set it to your variable (you're half way there!).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137547.aspx

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/03/11/SSIS-Nugget_3A00_-Setting-expressions.aspx

Comment: I am getting the result from web service task in the form of xml then how I am suppose to assign the values to the variable from that XML file

Comment: ...the fact is I don't want save data in any xml or any other format, as soon as web service performs it task then data should be transferred into variable then from that variable I want to put that data in database.

Comment: Apologies I think I misunderstood initially -- So you want to take data returned from a web service and put it into a database?  Is the database always going to be the same?  What sort of web service is it (e.g. REST, SOAP, etc.)?  You should be able to consume the data from the database and transform it as needed to fit into your database.  Here is a link describing that:  http://www.aptude.com/it/easyblog/entry/ssis-calling-a-webservice-by-using-the-webservice-task

Comment: @mikey...I hv tried the above eg but the thing is I am unable to insert the data into table , When I am trying to insert the data by the following query command written in OLEDB Source Editor, "INSERT INTO Data_Result(Result) SElECT '"+@USER::my_data+"'", then it's giving error.... Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [55]]: No Column  Transformation was return by SQL Command and it's seems it's selecting the table whereas I want to insert data into Data_Result from the variable my_data..

Comment: @Reshma - It sounds like you likely have a couple of different issues.  I'll address one of them.  If you want to INSERT data into a table, you should do it with a "Data Flow Destination" not a "Data Flow Source".

Comment: @mikey...I am making use of Web service task and data flow task in control flow, my web service task performs well and can give output in xml file but I want that output in variable so that variable I can use in OLEDB Destination in data flow task to insert data into table, when I am setting the OLEDB destination, it is first saying component has no available inputs and when I am still trying for it then in data access mode , if I select Table or view then unable to get the inputs in mapping and if I select table name or variable then it's showing destination table name not provided.

Comment: @mikey..and also if i am selecting sql command mode then I am unable to write the insert query, it's always giving syntax error, I dnt want to take data from any source but directlye insert that data into table from variable..I am writing the query as "insert into Data_Result(Result) values ('"+@User:Data+"')", here, Data_Result is destination Table, Result is column where data has to be inserted and User::Data is the User Variable which I am using to store the result from web service task...

Comment: Reshna as I mentioned in one of your many other posts... you're missing square brackets around your variable name. Do some research and check what an expression looks like.

Comment: @ElectricLlama.. Can you please tell me the solution for the problem of I am trying to create the Integration Service Catalog in SSMS for deploying the SSIS package and when I am trying to configure it then it is saying the password doesn't meet the requirement of  password filter dll, I am not able to find the proper articles to help me with this.